# capture and save string to local file

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple app with which I want to capture a string and save it to a file within the app directory. Is it possible to use $http to post/put to a file within the app tree similar to how you'd get static files like views?

Thanks

C

Answer (score -1):

Use  HTML5 filesystem API. [Example here](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#filewriter).